# Matching value and return value based on condtion

Tags: excel, match, vlookup

I have 2 spread sheets

On sheet 1 I have 2 columns (Prop_id and Code)  sheet 2 I have 2 columns (prop_id and Store)

I need to match Prop_id in sheet 2 with Prop_id in sheet 1 which have some duplicate id, 
and then return value from code based on a condition,

If `code=Ma` type Ma in Store column in sheet 2

If `code=CP` type CP in Store Column in sheet 2

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use `IF` and `COUNTIFS` like follows:

Sheet1 is above, Sheet2 is below:

[image]

The formula in Sheet2 cell B2 is:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(Sheet1!$A:$A,$A2,Sheet1!$B:$B,"MA")>0,"MA","")
```

And that in cell C2 is:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(Sheet1!$A:$A,$A2,Sheet1!$B:$B,"CP")>0,"CP","")
```

Details:

`COUNTIFS` counts the number of rows that satisfy certain conditions. The conditions I applied are:

1. The column A of Sheet1 (`Sheet1!$A:$A`) needs to be equal to A2 (the `Prop_id`)
2. The column B of Sheet1 (`Sheet1!$B:$B`) needs to be equal to `MA`.

If there are more than 0 rows that satisfy the condition, then that means that the Prop_id with Code `MA` exists and tells Excel to put `MA`.

The same logic goes for `CP`.

Comment: Many thanks Jerry,  I test it but, for example in sheet 1  I had this one: Prop_id  had these value  82, 82, 82, 82  and code had these value, MA, AG, CP, MA2,   the formula returning only MA,  I don't mind adding another column for CP in sheet 2

Comment: @user2722043 Oh, okay, that calls for another approach then. For your example of 82, do you want to get one cell typed `MA` and another `CP`? If that's okay with two columns (definitely easier), I'll edit my answer to do that.

Comment: Yes that will be fine, I do appreciate that,  Just please explain that, so If i need to change the code value in the future

Comment: @user2722043 Okay, I edited my answer. Do let me know if that's clear enough, and if not, I'll try to elaborate more.

Comment: @user2722043 Awesome! Glad to have saved someone tonight :)

Comment: If I can do the same solution with SQL tables

Comment: I just Accepted your answer is there any think else to rank your answer

Comment: @user2722043 That's fine, don't worry about it. You can start voting up/down when you have at least 20 rep points, but that's okay. You have to do that for SQL too? I could try writing a query.

Comment: @user2722043 What is the SQL flavour that you use?

Comment: @user2722043 I put it on a SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a13416/2) if that's of any help.